# Редирект и проигрывание звука на 2 странице по нажатию кнопки на 1 странице [JS+HTML]

Tags: javascript, html

**Доброй ночи.**

HTML

```
 <audio id="sound"><source src="eas alarm.mp3" type="audio/mp3"></audio>
<input type="submit" value="ALARM (test)" form="order_form" id="button" class="button" onclick="playSound('sound'); setTimeout('alert(\'SEAS SECTON 1 RAN SUCCEFSULLY\')', 7000)"">
```

JS

```
    function playSound(sound) {
    var song = document.getElementById(sound);
    song.volume = 1;
    console.log("SEAS: TEST ALARM SECTION PREPARING");
    console.log("SEAS: TEST ALARM STARTED");
    console.log("SEAS: TEST ALARM SET");
    console.log("TEST ALARM!");
    if (song.paused) {
      song.play();
    } else {
      song.pause();
    }
  }
```

после нажатия на кнопку воспроизводиться звук и запись в консоль лог.

**мне нужно что бы  после нажатия на кнопку, код выполнялся уже на другой страничке HTML**

возможно в реализовать? или гемор? подскажите пожалуйста, заранее благодарен

Comment: были мысли по поводу window.location.href="page.html";
но тогда не выйдет сделать авто звук, да и условия не построишь что ЕСЛИ кнопка нажата то тогда выполнять код

Comment: Мож фреймы? Сделать фрейм с 0 длниой или шириной и в него звук запихнуть. А по ссылкам обновлять не все окно, а основной фрейм?

Comment: Либо просто Ajax'ом обновлять блок с контентом, а блок с аудио не трогать

Comment: если обе страницы подключены к одному бэку, конечно. в почти любой соцке\CMS смотрите ajax уведомления о новых сообщениях.

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению, воспроизведение не может быть запущено на второй странице, т к браузер будет это воспринимать, как попытку автозапуска воспроизведения. (хотя это фактически происходит по нажатию на кнопку) В какой-то степени обойти это можно с помощью автооткрытия новой вкладки браузера, в которой будет находиться плеер. Управлять им можно будет с первой вкладки кнопкой. И всё равно этот плеер не будет работать до тех пор, пока на второй странице посетитель не совершит пользовательское действие. (хотя бы клик по пустому месту).

```html
<input type="submit" value="ALARM (test)" form="order_form" id="button" class="button" onclick="playSound('sound'); setTimeout('alert(\'SEAS SECTON 1 RAN SUCCEFSULLY\')', 7000)">
<script>
var myWindow = window.open("", "", "");
let song = myWindow.document.createElement("audio");
song.src = "eas alarm.mp3";
song.volume = 1;
song.controls = true;
myWindow.document.body.appendChild(song);
function playSound(sound) {
    console.log("SEAS: TEST ALARM SECTION PREPARING");
    console.log("SEAS: TEST ALARM STARTED");
    console.log("SEAS: TEST ALARM SET");
    console.log("TEST ALARM!");
    if (song.paused) {
      song.play();
    } else {
      song.pause();
    }
  }
</script>
```

Есть ещё такой вариант. Пользуясь тем, что метод **document.write()** имеет такое удивительное свойство - если его вызывать нажатием на кнопку, то отображаемое содержимое появляется как бы на новой странице, но в той же вкладке браузера. Т. е., всё остальное просто исчезает. Вернуться обратно можно браузерной кнопкой **назад**.

```html
<input type="submit" value="ALARM (test)" form="order_form" id="button" class="button" onclick="playSound(); setTimeout('alert(\'SEAS SECTON 1 RAN SUCCEFSULLY\')', 7000)">
<script>
function playSound() {
    document.write("<audio id=sound src='eas alarm.mp3' controls></audio>");
    sound.play();
}
</script>
```

Comment: По поводу первого варианта, все равно воспроизводиться на одной странице. По поводу второго варианта, идея прикольная, ток не работает аудио почему-то :) А так спасибо!